# Two statistics on the permutation group

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups

Let $\mathfrak{S}_n$ be the permutation group on an $n$-element set. For each fixed $k\in\mathbb{N}$, consider the two sets
$$A_n(k)=\{\sigma\in\mathfrak{S}_n\vert\,\, \text{$\exists i,\,\, 1\leq i\leq n\,$ such that $\,\sigma(i)-i=k$}\}$$
and 
$$B_n(k)=\{\sigma\in\mathfrak{S}_n\vert\,\, \text{$\exists i,\,\, 1\leq i\leq n\,$ such that $\,\sigma(i+1)-\sigma(i)=k$}\}.$$

> **QUESTION.** I believe the following is true, for each $n$ and $k$:
>   $$\# A_n(k)=\# B_n(k).$$
>   Is there a **combinatorial** proof of this? If it is known, then can you provide references?

Comment: Isn't $A_n(0)$ the set of non-derangements (i.e., those permutations having a fixed point), while $B_n(0) = \emptyset$?

Comment: Okay, it appears to hold for $k>0$ (tested for $n \leq 8, 1 \leq k \leq n$.

Comment: usual suspects here :-) - yes, apparently $\mathbb N=\{1,2,3,\dots\}$.

Comment: Since this generalises the equidistribution of descents and excedences, you might get lucky with one of the bijections showing this.

Comment: Indeed, I just checked that - experimentally -- for each $k$ the distribution of the number of $k$-excedences equals the distribution of $k$-descents.

Comment: So Martin's statement is even more refined, it appears. The PIs question is whether the number of permutations having a k-descent is the same as the number of permutations having a k-excedence. And Martin (and actually my test above also) tests for the distribution of k-descents is the same as the distribution of k-excedences.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A simple variant of the "transformation fondamentale" of Rényi and
of Foata-Schützenberger does the trick. Write a permutation $\sigma$ in
disjoint cycle form, with the smallest element of each cycle first,
and the cycles arranged in decreasing order of the smallest element,
e.g., $(7,8)(5,6,9)(3)(1,4,2)$. Erase the parentheses to get another
permutation $\hat{\sigma}$, written as a word, e.g., $785693142$. This gives
a bijection $\mathfrak{S}_n\to\mathfrak{S}_n$ with the property that
$\sigma(i)-i=k>0$ if and only if
$\hat{\sigma}(j+1)-\hat{\sigma}(j)=k$, where $\hat{\sigma}(j)=i$.

Comment: I think that this is precisely what Find Stat found, reproduced in the other answer.

Comment: @Stanley: I like this cute and crisp proof.

Answer (score 6):

You can use sage and www.findstat.org to find a candidate for a bijection as follows.  First define the statistics you are interested in:

```
def A_num(s, k):
    return len([1 for i,e in enumerate(s,1) if e-i==k])

def B_num(s, k):
    return len([1 for e,f in zip(s, s[1:]) if f-e==k])
```

Then ask, what findstat knows about them:

```
sage: findstat("Permutations", lambda s: A_num(s, 2), depth=3)
0: (St000534: The number of 2-rises of a permutation., [Mp00066: inverse, Mp00087: inverse first fundamental transformation, Mp00064: reverse], 200)

sage: findstat("Permutations", lambda s: B_num(s, 2), depth=3)
0: (St000534: The number of 2-rises of a permutation., [], 200)

sage: findstat("Permutations", lambda s: A_num(s, 1), depth=3)
0: (St000237: The number of indices $i$ such that $\pi_i=i+1$., [], 200)
1: (St000214: The number of adjacencies (or small descents) of a permutation., [Mp00066: inverse, Mp00087: inverse first fundamental transformation], 200)
2: (St000441: The number of successions (or small ascents) of a permutation., [Mp00066: inverse, Mp00087: inverse first fundamental transformation, Mp00064: reverse], 200)

sage: findstat("Permutations", lambda s: B_num(s, 1), depth=3)
0: (St000441: The number of successions (or small ascents) of a permutation., [], 200)
1: (St000214: The number of adjacencies (or small descents) of a permutation., [Mp00064: reverse], 200)
2: (St000237: The number of indices $i$ such that $\pi_i=i+1$., [Mp00064: reverse, Mp00086: first fundamental transformation, Mp00066: inverse], 200)
```

So, this suggests that using the composition of the maps http://www.findstat.org/MapsDatabase/Mp00066,
http://www.findstat.org/MapsDatabase/Mp00087
and
http://www.findstat.org/MapsDatabase/Mp00064
might be a good idea.  No guarantee, of course.

Comment: I think this is an answer -- I also tested this, and this combination of maps does yield the desired bijection for $n \leq 8$ and all $k$.

Comment: I guess I should now create a new mathoverflow account Find Stat.  Is Shalosh Ekhad a mathoverflow user?

Comment: To see this bijection in action, you can go to www.findstat.org/St000650 and then click on "search for values" to find that the third hit is exactly this map.

Comment: @MartinRubey: this is a good tool. Thank you!

Comment: @MartinRubey: Regarding Ekhad, you may contact Doron Zeilberger.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan thank you.  Besides, if you follow the link to Mp00087, you'll find (essentially) Richard's description.